# Update d3js set of object by iterating over already plotted objects?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have an SVG graph that contains a set of circles that are plotted from  array of objects ***d*** :

```
  svg.selectAll(".circ").data(d)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("cy", function (d) {
                return d.y
            })
            .attr("cx", function (d) {
                return d.x
            })
            .attr("r", elemSize / 2)
            .style("fill", function (d) {
                return d.color
            }).attr("class", function (d, i) {
                return "containerCell circ";
            })
```

I have also array called ***states*** that contains new fill colors, that has the same size/indexes as inital ***d***.

What expression in d3js I can use to go over the already plotted elements and update their fill color from the one stored in ***states*** ? Perhaps I need to use some iteration approach over already existing objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer myself.

```
 // select all circles of interest
 var select = svg.selectAll(".circ"); 
        if (!select.empty()) { // if selection got something
            select.each(function (d, i) {
                // d is data, i is index and we can modify elements of SVG as follows:
                d3.select(this).style("fill", statusColor(states[i]));
            });
        }
```